# Google drive API Dredit Jplayer

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, jplayer

I'm attempting to work from Dredit (the sample drive application) to try to develop an app that can be used to play music off google drive using Jplayer. I have Jplayer installed on index.jsp, but I don't know how to interact with it, or where I need to change the code. I know at some point the code is using the Java Script ace text reader to read the files.  I Instead want to use the Jplayer Javscript. I'v also never interacted with Java Script files using a Java Servlet or Java code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some more specifics on where you are stuck would be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just some pointers:

You'll need to pass the downloadURL of the file (it is in the file metadata that you get from the API) to Jplayer. For that you can for, example, simply write on the rendered HTML or use some AJAX callbacks.

You'll also need to pass the OAuth 2.0 access token so that you can authorize your request to the file so for instance you'll use Jplayer to read the audio fil located at:

downloadUrl + '&access_token=' + accessToken